# Why is Nearest not giving me expected result

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have the following list:

```
numbers={0.,0.6,0.8,1.,1.2,1.4,1.8}
```

Then I calculate the midpoints:

```
midpoints=Table[0.5*(numbers[[ii+1]]+numbers[[ii]]),{ii,Length[numbers]-1}]

>>> {0.3,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.6}
```

When I plug this into `Nearest`, I get sometimes two numbers, sometimes the lower and sometimes the upper:

```
Nearest[numbers,#]&/@midpoints

>>> {{0.,0.6},{0.6},{0.8,1.},{1.2},{1.2},{1.8}}
```

By the way, this other form for calculating the midpoints is giving me strange results:

```
(0.5*(numbers[[# + 1]] + numbers[[#]])) & /@ (Range@Length@numbers - 1)

>>> {0.5 (0. +List), 0.6, 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3.2}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Regarding the last issue, use `Range[1, Length@numbers - 1]` instead of `Range@Length@numbers - 1`.

Comment: I think you have two questions here. Your question on Nearest could be: Why do `Nearest[{0.6,0.8},0.7]` give one result (0.6), while `Nearest[{0.8,1.0},0.9]` give two results (0.8 and 1.0)? About your construction of midpoints, I don't see what is wrong with your approach, but another way would be `midpoints = ReplaceList[numbers, {___, a_, b_, ___} -> Mean[{a, b}]]`.

Comment: From the documentation - If the internal implementation is using Round this could explain your results. Round rounds numbers of the form x.5 toward the nearest even integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a rounding problem. You can see it from:

```
numbers = Rationalize@{0., 0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.8}
midpoints = MovingAverage[numbers, 2]
Nearest[numbers, #] & /@ midpoints


(* {{0, 3/5}, {3/5, 4/5}, {4/5, 1}, {1, 6/5}, {6/5, 7/5}, {7/5, 9/5}} *)
```

BTW, for long lists and reusable results use Nearest this way:

```
f = Nearest[numbers];
f /@ midpoints
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that there were these rounding problems. Is there a logic behind it, to see when it would round up and when down or it just depends on the machine precision or something?

Comment: @Santi I don't know. And that's probably prone to change from one version to the next.